# Close button in chrome packaged apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a chrome packaged app, and the white window was annoying me.
So I decided to make my own close/minimize/maximize buttons.
But, onclick doesn't work. And my workaround doesn't either.
HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="close"><img src="close.png"/></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var close = document.getElementById('close');
close.addEventListener('click', chrome.app.window.current().close);
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answer works if you use a separate `.js` file in your `.html` or use the one `.js` file which you use for your background scripting. I used this method.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('/*element-id*/').onclick = function() {
        chrome.app.window.current().close();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You close an packaged app like a web app with the code :

```
  document.getElementById("close").onclick = function() {
    window.close();
  }
```

You have sample here :
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/frameless-window/frameless_window.js

In this frameless package app sample :
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/frameless-window